# cannot add computed field to new record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, updates

I am creating a new customer record in my customers table.  However, in addition to the first and last names, I want to add a "full_name" field.  So, after the successful creation of the record (using params) I try to update the new full_name attribute, but it is not getting saved.  Here is the code that creates the new record:

```
  def create
    @customer = Customer.new(customer_params)
    if @customer.save
      redirect_to customer_index_path
    else
      render 'new'  # user entered values available in @customer
    end
  end
```

Here is how I modified the code to compute the full name and update the record:

```
  def create
    # todo this is not storing full_name
    fn = params[:first_name].to_s.strip
    ln = params[:last_name].to_s.strip
    @customer = Customer.new(customer_params)
    if @customer.save
      # construct full name & save (again) before redirecting
      @customer[:full_name] = fn + ' ' + ln
      @customer.save
      redirect_to customer_index_path
    else
      render 'new'  # user entered values available in @customer
    end
  end
```

But it is not saving the full_name to the db. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work. Replace second `@customer.save` with `@customer.save!`, and see if that save is performing as expected.

I'd use ActiveRecord callbacks for this kind of behaviour. You shouldn't put so much stuff in your controllers.

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :set_full_name

  private

  def set_full_name
    self.full_name = "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, Magnuss.  I'm still not sure why my code was not working, but your approach was much better.  I implemented your suggestion to add code to the model, and it is working now.  Thank you.